# Show or Hide the visibility of specific div with two links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a javascript function which toggle the visibility of a form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide(){
    var toggle = document.getElementById('form');
    if(toggle.style.display == 'none')
         toggle.style.display = 'block';
    else
         toggle.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

It is working fine with this link.

```
<a href="#" onclick="showHide()">Add new:</a>
```

But when I use this function in this link, it's not working. On clicking this link, page reloaded and hidden content is not displaying.

```
<a href="products.php?act=edit&id=1" onclick="showHide()">Edit</a>
```

Here is demo:
[products.php](http://www.moeen.webege.com/test/products.php)

I want same working of both "Add new:" & "Edit" links to show or hide the form with out reloading the page.

Comment: What did you expect ? You're linking to a page so you replace the content of the current one, the script is lost.

Comment: use PHP instead; set a SESSION variable or a GET variable that will work from page to page.

Comment: @dystroy These links are on same page(products.php) for same hidden content. I want when I click on "Add new" or on "Edit", it show me the hidden content. but when I click on "Edit" It reloads the page and not showing the content.

Comment: Change  
<a href="products.php?act=edit&id=1" onclick="showHide()">Edit</a>
to  
<a href="#" onclick="showHide()">Edit</a>

Although I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can simplify the function:

```
function showHide(){
    var toggleStyle = document.querySelector('#form').style;
    toggleStyle.display = toggleStyle.display ? '' : 'none';
}​
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/j3pLy/)

Second, your click-action *does* work, but because the href triggers a page refresh, it's not visible. If you want to use `showHide`, you could add a parameter to the href, something like: `<a href="products.php?act=edit&id=1&showform=1">`, and use the `showform` value on page load to trigger visibility. Alternatively you could use a cookie to 'remember' the form display state. A third alternative would be to use [XmlHTTPRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) (XHR, aka Ajax), to prevent a page refresh.

Answer (score 3):

as vatiant you can go this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide(){
    var toggle = document.getElementById('form');
    if(toggle.style.display == 'none')
         toggle.style.display = 'block';
    else
         toggle.style.display = 'none';
    document.location.href = 'http://yourdomain.com/products.php?act=edit&id=1'; //<<<<
}
</script>


<a href="#" onclick="showHide()">Add new:</a>
```

but do not understan for what =)

Comment: I realise it's not required for single-line statements, but using curly-braces is good practice, especially when advising someone unused to JavaScript (if only to prevent the *next* question being "my `if` was working, now it's not..! *Why?*" when things are updated/amended). Also: `toggle.style.display = toggle.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';` condenses things a little. =)

Answer (score 1):

If you're linking to another page / reloading the current page (which causes all state to be lost) then you need some way of passing the visibility of your div into the new page. You could

```
<a href="products.php?act=edit&id=1&visible=formVisible" onclick="showHide()">Edit</a>
```

You would need to set the `formVisible` value in your toggle function, or dynamically modify the links... there are many ways you could accomplish that.

As a side note you should use the [triple equals in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/96505)

```
if(toggle.style.display === 'none')
```